# In Windows, local kernel debugging is disabled by default. Why?

Tags: windows, debugging, windows-10, kernel, livekd

I'm using Windows 10.

When you first install Windows, local kernel debugging (`windbg -kl`) is disabled by default. To enable it, you must run `bcdedit -debug on` and reboot. (Though, as far as I can tell, Sysinternals LiveKd seems to work fine even when local kernel debugging is disabled.)

Why is local kernel debugging disabled by default? Is there any disadvantage to leaving it always enabled?

Comment: Having it always enabled would be a security risk of course, allowing malware to do what windbg does.

Comment: @HansPassant: `windbg -kl` requires administrative privileges to work. If I grant administrative privileges to some malware, I've already lost the game.

Comment: Wrong kind of game, an admin still lives in userland.  Kind of pointless to argue about this.

Comment: @HansPassant: I did more research. Kernel-mode malware has more access to the victim's hardware; such malware can also be challenging to detect and remove. But it's hard to write kernel-mode malware, and it's even harder to write kernel-mode malware that won't crash and cause a blue screen. Therefore, malware makers rarely bother writing kernel-mode malware. [(Source.)](http://www.cs.bu.edu/~goldbe/teaching/HW55813/zhou.pdf)

Comment: @HansPassant: Elevated user-mode malware can install a kernel-mode driver. The developer may have to buy a code-signing certificate first. [(Source.)](http://www.cs.bu.edu/~goldbe/teaching/HW55813/zhou.pdf) But they can get a one-year code-signing certificate for just US$75 or so.

Comment: @HansPassant: If an attacker can run `windbg -kl`, maybe they can install kernel-mode malware without getting it signed. This saves them $75 and lets them avoid some paperwork. But, because most people haven't enabled local kernel debugging, I suspect that most attackers won't bother trying this route.

Comment: Most people, when committing a crime, tend to try to avoid paperwork wherever possible. :-)  The theory is that you have to identify yourself to get a code-signing certificate, so if you use it to sign malware you're going to get caught.  How well that works in practice I don't know.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: It works well enough so that nation states supposedly had to steal certificates (and their private keys) form various Taiwanese companies to sign their drivers. How hard it was I don't know, but it was certainly harder than having to do nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, kernel debugging is disabled by default because it allows (even on 64-bit Windows) loading not-really-signed (self-signed) kernel drivers. (And disabling PatchGuard, etc.)

The comment about "an admin still lives in userland" is nonsense, of course. Commenter should go ahead and read Raymond Chen's posts about "[being](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060508-22/?p=31283) [on](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070807-00/?p=25683) [the](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100114-00/?p=15273) [other](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121207-00/?p=5893) [side](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130705-00/?p=3883) [of](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140529-00/?p=863) [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140703-00/?p=583) [airtight](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141217-00/?p=43373) [hatchway](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150923-00/?p=91531)". Allow me to use his words:

> I think you know how this story ends. If you have administrator privileges, then you are already on the other side of the airtight hatchway. That you can use administrator privileges to pwn the machine is not interesting, because by virtue of being an administrator you already pwn the machine.
>
> There is formally a distinction between Administrator and SYSTEM, seeing as they are some things which are ACL'd so that SYSTEM can do them and not arbitrary adminitrators, but that distinction is formal and not practical. An administrator who wanted to get some code running as SYSTEM could install a service that runs as SYSTEM. Or use Debug Privilege to take over a process (say, a service) running as SYSTEM. Or simply open a command prompt as SYSTEM and go to town. No need to go through the complex operation Q to get SYSTEM access.

The first sentence holds if you replace SYSTEM with kernel-mode driver.

You were right in your deleted comment that an administrator can load drivers, but on x64 they have to be signed.

What being able to load unsigned driver saves you is not 75 USD or filling an online form, but rather providing a provable identity. A kernel-mode code signing certificate is not the same as a domain-validated SSL certificate.

Note that Microsoft *intends* to require kernel mode drivers to be WHQL-certified (or use "attestation signing", supposedly only on non-Server SKUs), which requires submitting the drivers to Microsoft, and opening a Windows Hardware Developer account using an EV certificate. Hey! What's up with that? Is this a conspiracy colluded with CAs to make us pay more for certificates? Maybe. And maybe they want to be sure of your identity and are delegating the verification to the CAs (assuming that EV does what it's supposed to do).

Security-wise, this does not establish a real security boundary, but rather a mild mitigation. But there are other considerations: Microsoft doesn't want software publishers to install lousy drivers that take Windows down with them; and, if they happen to do it, Microsoft wants to know who wrote these drivers. That's the rationale behind attestation signing.

If you could easily enable kernel debugging, you can bet that some second-rate ISV would write lousy driver, without bothering to test or sign it, and would install it using that hack. (Actually, I know *today* of not-so-lousy ISVs that sign their drivers but don't WHQL-certify them, and use hacks to install them without any prompt. This is a real thing.)

Of course, the same lousy ISV can enable kernel debugging in its installer (which runs elevated), and can have its driver load after the next restart. But there's this annoying message on the desktop saying you're running in test signing mode to protect you from that. Sure, the same lousy ISV can hack around and hide the message, but at this point it may be easier to just get the certificate. This doesn't *prevent* anything, but it provides a mitigation by making it annoying enough so they won't bother.

If you wonder why enabling kernel debugging puts you in test signing mode, the answer is: Because that's the usual and intended scenario. There's a registry value you can change to require production signing even when kernel debugging, but that's the exceptional case. The default is correct for the common scenario. You have LiveKD. There's no reason for Microsoft to bend over backwards to deal with a scenario that doesn't really happen. They've got enough problems as it is. Like fixing all those crashes in Microsoft Edge.